# How to search and resize images with dimensions higher than ... in Unix cli

Tags: image, resize, find, command-line-interface, mogrify

How can i find and resize images with resolution higher that X width in unix cli?
I have tried

```
find -name *.jpg -exec mogrify -resize 800x800 -format jpg {} \;
```

but the problem is that resizes also the images that have width or height below from 800 pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it. This is it:

```
find * -iname '*.jpg' -print0 | xargs -0 mogrify -resize 800x800\> -monitor -format jpg
```